# Hardware Sizing for MobileFirst 7.1 Analytics

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are planning to add a new application to our current server where we already have one application. Currently, we have 2 Analytics server in the cluster. As we are adding this new application which will have a huge user base, we are thinking to add new analytics servers to the cluster.

To determine how many servers we need to add, we filled the hardware_calculator given [in this link](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/learn-more/#sc-ha-sizing).

Current Application - user logging each day average 3000 (10 transactions each)
New Application- expected user logging each day average 20000(10 transactions each).

Notice the attached image screen shot of hardware_calculator sheet, when I filled the new application user counts as 20000 and 10 transactions each. The recommended number of physical nodes comes out to 36. This seems a huge number.

Please help me to know if I am missing anything here. Is this the right way to enter counts for analytics hardware_calculator.

[image: screenHardware_calculator]

Comment: The question on line#10 - "How many days you want to keep the data ?" - You have provided days (1760) which is a large number. That is nearly 5 years. Please correct them. That is one of the important reasons you get that numbers.

Comment: @krckumar What does this field refers to. Is it actual data like adapter hit count, session count etc or it refers to the client or server log files?

Comment: That field refers to the number of days your complete historic data has to be kept on the disk for showing on console

Comment: @krckumar oh ok if that so then we definitely want to keep analytical data for 5 yeas.  We don't care a lot about client debug log or server log, but server usage stats we want to retain for few years.

Comment: @krckumar Is there any way we can backup yearly data and at a time only keep 365 days stats. And also have the ability to go back and look at backup data when required.

Comment: Sorry, currently we don't support to go back to a backup data like that.

Comment: But having 36 servers does not seems practicel. Do u know if there is any other way ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145084/discussion-between-krckumar-and-mobilefirst-developer).

Comment: I have one more question. Regarding how can I add new analytical server to current cluster of 2. Is there any documentation which might have details steps.